# GraphQL Code Generator - Failed to load schema from http://localhost:8000/graphql - Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

Tags: django, graphql, react-query, graphql-codegen, strawberry-graphql

I've built a GraphQL API using [strawberry](https://strawberry.rocks/) and [strawberry-django-plus](https://github.com/blb-ventures/strawberry-django-plus) that is hosted on http://localhost:8000/graphql using Django.  I am able to successfully interact with the API using GraphiQL on the localhost page.

I'm now trying to access the API from my frontend using [GraphQL Code Generator](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator) and React Query.  When I run the command `yarn graphql-codegen`, the following error occurs:

```
✔ Parse configuration
  ❯ Generate outputs
    ❯ Generate src/generated/graphql.ts
      ✖ Load GraphQL schemas
        → Failed to load schema
        Load GraphQL documents
        Generate
    ❯ Generate ./graphql.schema.json
      ✖ Load GraphQL schemas
        → Failed to load schema
        Load GraphQL documents
        Generate


 Found 2 errors

  ✖ ./graphql.schema.json
    Failed to load schema from http://localhost:8000/graphql:

        Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
        TypeError: Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
    at new Request (mydir/.yarn/cache/undici-npm-5.6.0-b513316628-b9052c2cb9.zip/node_modules/
undici/lib/fetch/request.js:437:13)
    at Agent.fetch (mydir/.yarn/cache/undici-npm-5.6.0-b513316628-b9052c2cb9.zip/node_modules/
undici/lib/fetch/index.js:114:21)
    at fetch (mydir/.yarn/cache/undici-npm-5.6.0-b513316628-b9052c2cb9.zip/node_modules/undici
/index.js:90:22)
    at fetch (mydir/.yarn/cache/cross-undici-fetch-npm-0.4.8-4bdc960eeb-7645fde142.zip/node_mo
dules/cross-undici-fetch/dist/create-node-ponyfill.js:130:16)
    at fetch (mydir/.yarn/cache/cross-undici-fetch-npm-0.4.8-4bdc960eeb-7645fde142.zip/node_mo
dules/cross-undici-fetch/dist/create-node-ponyfill.js:125:18)
    at defaultAsyncFetch (mydir/.yarn/__virtual__/@graphql-tools-url-loader-virtual-1d0d6b13ee
/0/cache/@graphql-tools-url-loader-npm-7.12.0-ad4affabf8-6db87eec05.zip/node_modules/@graphql-tools/url-loader/cjs/defaultAsyncFetch.js:6:43)
    at mydir/.yarn/__virtual__/@graphql-tools-url-loader-virtual-1d0d6b13ee/0/cache/@graphql-t
ools-url-loader-npm-7.12.0-ad4affabf8-6db87eec05.zip/node_modules/@graphql-tools/url-loader/cjs/index.js:212:36
    at new ValueOrPromise (mydir/.yarn/cache/value-or-promise-npm-1.0.11-924f226d8c-13f8f2ef62
.zip/node_modules/value-or-promise/build/main/ValueOrPromise.js:14:21)
    at executor (mydir/.yarn/__virtual__/@graphql-tools-url-loader-virtual-1d0d6b13ee/0/cache/
@graphql-tools-url-loader-npm-7.12.0-ad4affabf8-6db87eec05.zip/node_modules/@graphql-tools/url-loader/cjs/index.js:186:20)
    at mydir/.yarn/__virtual__/@graphql-tools-url-loader-virtual-1d0d6b13ee/0/cache/@graphql-t
ools-url-loader-npm-7.12.0-ad4affabf8-6db87eec05.zip/node_modules/@graphql-tools/url-loader/cjs/index.js:504:35

        GraphQL Code Generator supports:
          - ES Modules and CommonJS exports (export as default or named export "schema")
          - Introspection JSON File
          - URL of GraphQL endpoint
          - Multiple files with type definitions (glob expression)
          - String in config file

        Try to use one of above options and run codegen again.
    Error: Failed to load schema
        at loadSchema (mydir/.yarn/__virtual__/@graphql-codegen-cli-virtual-7cdefe09f5/0/cache
/@graphql-codegen-cli-npm-2.6.4-2c119c03ca-664fbd395f.zip/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:507:15)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async mydir/.yarn/__virtual__/@graphql-codegen-cli-virtual-7cdefe09f5/0/cache/@grap
hql-codegen-cli-npm-2.6.4-2c119c03ca-664fbd395f.zip/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:1037:65
    Error: Failed to load schema
        at loadSchema (mydir/.yarn/__virtual__/@graphql-codegen-cli-virtual-7cdefe09f5/0/cache
/@graphql-codegen-cli-npm-2.6.4-2c119c03ca-664fbd395f.zip/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:507:15)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async mydir/.yarn/__virtual__/@graphql-codegen-cli-virtual-7cdefe09f5/0/cache/@grap
hql-codegen-cli-npm-2.6.4-2c119c03ca-664fbd395f.zip/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:1037:65
```

Here is my `codegen.yml` file:

```yaml
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:8000/graphql"
documents: "src/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093753/graphql-failed-to-load-schema-from-http-localhost5555-graphql-fetch-failed) question deals with a similar problem; however, I am sure that my server is running and the error message in that question is different.  I have also read [this](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/4095) GitHub issue on `graphql-code-generator`; however, it does not deal with loading the schema from localhost.

Any help is much appreciated.  I can share my backend code if needed; however, I believe the issue is occurring in the frontend.

Comment: are you able to check if codegen is sending a POST or a GET request?

Comment: @patrick From the error message, I'd assume that it's sending a GET request.  However, the GET request is never actually reaching my server as it's simply failing as it attempts to send

Comment: Experiencing the same now. My localhost is serving the GraphiQL interface just fine, showing the correct schema and all, but the code-generator script shows the same as yours. Funny thing is, it worked as expected a couple days ago. I hope it's not a faulty npm package.

Comment: What I did for now is download the SDL schema from Apollo Studio and change the `codegen.yaml` config file to generate from the schema file instead of fetching it. This error makes no sense and I'm pretty sure it's a dependency problem. Hope you figure it out soon.

Comment: if you can post a small reproductions somewhere I'll be happy to take a look 

Comment: Running into the same problems here, on a relatively fresh Vue project running on an Apollo mock server. Generating from local file works.

Answer (score 11):

I also encountered this issue.
I found that using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql` instead of `http://localhost:8000/graphql` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

A temporary fix has been suggested, and it has worked for me

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "undici": "5.5.1"
  }
}
```

Got it from the github issue that is going on.
https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/8012#issuecomment-1172725253